# android studio structural search and replace with regEx for search template

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-attributes

I want to implement mechanism for required xml custom attributes - exactly like layout_width/layout_height, but for custom attributes.

possible solution is adding structural search to inspections, but I could not make it search for xml without specific attributes, so after it replaces the text to the new one **with** the required attribute, is still shows an error.

can I search for template with regEx?
is there any other better solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + R` to open `find and replace on all project` and then select `File mask:` as `*.xml`

[image: file mask]

Comment: Try this [JetBrains link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html)